# Show an Ideal is the principal ideal for some polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld and $R = F[X]$. Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $R$. Show that $I = (p(X))$ for some $p(X)$ in $F[X]$. (Hint: consider a polynomial $p(X)$ of least degree in $I$.)

I'm trying to do this question but can't seem to start. if anyone could give me a hint that would be appreciated.

My instinct was to take a monic polynomial (which exists since we are in a field) of degree $1$ and divide given the first two parts of the question were about polynomial division.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be a bit more general then starting with a degree one polynomial. We are in a PID, so for example, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $x^2 + 1$ generates a principle ideal, however it is not of degree one. This is my first impression, mind you it's been a long time since I studied this stuff, and this is just a first attempt, but should get you started.

Let $p\in I$ be as the hint suggests. Now suppose that $f$ is some polynomial in $I$ such that $p\not|f$, then $f = gp + r$ for some $r$ with degree of $r<p$. Contradiction as this tells us that $r=f-gp\in I$, but we picked $p$ to be of least degree.

I think the point here is that we are in a PID or a ED actually, so ideals are prime/generated by one element which is irreducible.

Comment: You shouldn't, perhaps, be stressing that we're in a PID as this is **precisely** what this exercise tries to show. You probably should also remark (and leave the comprobation for the OP) that the contradiction follows because $\;r=f-gp\in I\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, he asked for a hint, not a complete solution, so that's exactly what I gave him. However, it's been a while, so perhaps you can answer me this: If we are going to write f=gp+r, then at some point we are going to have to assume we have some type of Euclidean function yes? That is ED implies PID, so have I made a mistake?

Comment: Excellent, I see by the solution posted, that I basically nailed it:p Of course why would someone just feed an answer like that? It's not the way to learn or teach math.Furthermore, as you can see DonAntonio, they have assumed they are in a Euclidean Domain just as I did.

Comment: good point on the hint thing, but as for the PID one: no, you can *not* assume in this question ED ==> PID as this is what the question's asking to prove. It's not a matter of making a mathematical *purely* mistake but a logical one, imo. +1

Comment: But in the proof below, they have used the division algorithm which is a Euclidean function, and in his question he stated that the earlier parts were doing polynomial division, so yes I jumped to the conclusion. Anyways, I will keep that in mind from now on....oh I see what you're saying...You're right, I didn't realize that was the order the curriculum went in. That is, right now he is studying ED, and this is where they find out about PID's.

Comment: One last comment, and just to be completely argumentative cause I like you so much;) In Hungerford's Algebra, It goes PID's then UFD's, then ER's/ED's.